# Passing textarea values, line break and symbols into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, textarea

I am passing the values from a textarea into a div as such:

```
$("#string").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function () { 
    var a = $('#string').val();
    $('#rdonly').html(a);
});
```

Know **I want to pass the line break, replace `&` with `'and'` so when ever you press Return/Enter a line break appears to the div.**

Here is what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/kC4GE/

If you press enter/return, the div continues to write on the same line.

I would assume it would be something with `replace()`event but I can't figure it out

Comment: BTW, you should also handle the `input` event.

Comment: It's a test. In reality I'm handling "keyup change cut paste input click keypress mouseup input". Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch all the ampersands and new-line characters you need to use a global flag on your regex:

```
$("#string").on("keyup keydown input keypress paste mouseup", function () {
    var a = $('#string').val().replace(/\n/g,'<br />')
                              .replace(/&/g,'and');
    $('#rdonly').html(a);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kC4GE/5/

Answer (score 2):

See this

http://jsfiddle.net/kC4GE/8/

Basically, use the javascript `replace()` function to replace all newlines (`\n`) to `<br>`

Similar for & to and.

Comment: Your demo only replaces the first instance of `\n`

Comment: It replaces it only the first time. Try return some words return some words continuously. Thats up to the point where I came to be honest

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't do the global check. See updated fiddle please.

Comment: One more thing, this won't catch ampersands that are: on their own line, the start of a line, or the end of a line.

Comment: @DavidThomas Does it make a difference in this case to use the "ignore case" flag?

Comment: @Jasper yes I know. I put that there in case someone enters an html entity like `&amp;` but I'm now realizing that shouldn't be worried about, since there's no `<` to `&lt;` etc. No spaces between the amps :)

Comment: @DavidThomas Just wondering... I'm pretty green when it comes to regex. Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: @Jasper, me too; take a look at the MDN's [Regexp page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for help =).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#string").on("keyup keypress paste mouseup", function () { 
    var a = $('#string').val();
    a = a.replace("\n","<br/>");
    a = a.replace("&","and");
    $('#rdonly').html(a);
});
```